# how to handle firebase auth exceptions in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i have developed a login page.but i don't know how to catch firebase auth exceptions on flutter and display them.i want to display something email doesn't exist, password didn't match.

Here's my code:

```
Future<void> login() async{
    final  formState = _formkey.currentState;
    if(formState.validate()){
      formState.save();
      try{

        final FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _username, password: _password)).user;

          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Admin()));
      }catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }
```

Can someone help me finding a way to validate the login please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Toast` to display the error:

```
# add this line to your dependencies
toast: ^0.1.5
```

Then in the dart file import it:

```
import 'package:toast/toast.dart';
```

Then inside the catch:

```
 }catch(e){
        print(e.message);
    Toast.show(e.message, context, duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity:  Toast.BOTTOM);    
 }
```

https://pub.dev/packages/toast

You don't have to check if the email is wrong or not, the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` already does that for you and will return an error if the authentication was wrong.

Comment: I want to validate the email and password like if it it's Wrong then a toast message should display

Comment: The signinwithemailandpassword returns the following errors https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#error-codes_12, Firebase validates the email and password.. All you need to do is use a Toast to inform the user

Comment: What is the problem

Comment: Why are you not able to implement

Comment: first i want to display only a error message when email or password is wrong that i'm not able to find that

Answer (score 0):

You could just display the `e.message` from your `catch block` to the user - if all you want is to display the message.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Hi Rohit, that's what @Peter explained earlier.